# How to increase height of a fragment by scrolling it down?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to show map fragment on a activity that user can expand it by scroll it down.
like this:

[image]

I put fragment container in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` for collapse it, and increase height of `appBarLayout` when `CoordinatorLayout` scrolling down to expand fragment.

```
coordinatorLayout.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    downY = event.y
                    lastY = downY
                    return true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    if (lastY == 0f) {
                        lastY = event.y
                        return true
                    }

                    val deltaY = event.y - lastY
                    lastY = event.y
                    val param = appBarLayout.layoutParams

                    if (deltaY > 0 || param.height > mapMinHeight) {
                        param.height += deltaY.roundToInt()
                        appBarLayout.layoutParams = param
                    }
                    return true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    lastY = 0f
                    expandCollapseMap()
                    return true
                }
            }

            return false
        }
    })
```

but it is laggy and have not good performance.
can you suggest a better way for this?